# settext() from created class makes my app crash

Tags: android

i am new to programming, i dont know much of the terminologies so please bear with me, 
i have this simple problem , i want to settext my textview from the value of scoring.java, (this is some part of the whole app im making for our assignment), i have already seen all the answers here and i cant find easy one.

//scoring.java

```
public class Scoring {

    public static  int Score= 0;

    public static int Sc(){
        Score ++;
        return Score;
    }
}
```

//score.java

```
package com.example.sti.bayonamobidevquiz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.*;


public class score extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_score);
        TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.finalscore);

        tv1.setText(Scoring.Score); 
    }
}
```

Comment: this is my first time to ask here,sorry for format errors,im using mobile

Comment: Please post the exact crash from Logcat that you are experiencing. My guess is that you need to do `tv1.setText(String.valueOf(Scoring.Score));`

Comment: ... and ensure that `tv1` is not null before applying `setText(...)`

Comment: i cant post a log cat, this is wierd to say but im just using Aide, i dont have computer , but thnx anyway

Comment: jesus christ thanks, adding string.valueof() works, i love u guys , how can i add  your reputation

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are probably facing is, that Android is looking for a Ressource with your `Scores` id - which it most likely will not find - so a `ResourcesNotFoundException` is thrown.

You need to use `tv1.setText(Interger.ValueOf(Scoring.Score));`...